# Shortlisting criteria for an oversubscribed course: first-come-first-served vs grade point and classroom diversity

Tags: coursework, grading, pre-registration

I teach an advanced Engineering elective course which has a mixed audience of Junior (3rd year) and Seinor (4th year) undergrads and some Grad students.   Since it is a interactive course with a lot of project based work etc. we are typically constrained to accepting not more than about 30 students (for reasons of grading time, vivas etc).

Somehow the course has gotten popular and we get many more students wanting to take the course. I wanted feedback on how other instructors handle this sort of situation.

The default at our University's online registration system is a first-come-first-served which I don't like so much. I am tending towards a grade point based shortlisting criteria (which is a lot of work since the registration system is not geared to handle this so I must do the shortlisting manually) but I also like to have a fairly even split between 3rd years / 4th years and Grad students since it makes for a better discussion and project groups. Maybe think of it as a classroom diversity of perspective.

Just curious to hear thought from others about shortlisting criteria and how much of "instructor discretion" vs a hard constraint / criterion is good.  Sometimes I get students who seem really interested (or have some past background which makes for a demonstrable interest in this course area) but may not get in according to a grade point shortlisting criterion. Is it ok to make such exemptions and allow them to register?

I guess, what's the tradeoff between some sort of objective "fairness" and a subjective evaluation by instructor.

Comment: What is CPI? ..

Comment: If you have actual authority to set your own criteria, don't neglect that some students may actually need the course to avoid a delay in their graduation. But, your chair and/or dean may need to be consulted before you implement anything. They can give you valid answers, whereas we cannot.

Comment: Does your university have regulations on this?  In the US context individual instructors typically have little or no control over these situations.

Answer (score 3):

The main problems with doing something unusual are that it is unfamiliar to your students, which could cause consternation if they feel they didn't receive enough info about how to get into your class, *especially* if it caused problems with their graduation plans.

At universities I'm familiar with, registration is allowed for grad students first, followed by seniors, then juniors, down the line. It would be really unfortunate to choose a third-year for the last spot and force a senior to take another year or semester because they couldn't get into your class because they had incomplete information.

"Instructor discretion" sounds like a recipe for mishandling individual qualifications, whether you want to talk about inherent bias or lack of information (GPA seems far too coarse for this).

A couple of simple ways to address your problem:

- Split grad students into a separate grad student class that meets at the same time with the undergrads.
- If you can in your registration system, reserve spots for non-seniors (common at universities I'm familiar with). While within-year, it would still be first-come-first-served, you would achieve your goal of having both third- and fourth-years.

Finally, I think having an application system would be OK, **but it needs to be handled transparently and early** so students can plan their schedule; i.e. your application is due early enough so that you can select your students before the **earliest registration date.** Ideally, you should have a second person help you evaluate. This also lets you ask for cover letters and CVs. You should be clear you are reserving, say, 10 spots for third-years. Then, you just lock registration and give codes to the students whom you selected.

Comment: "Default" may not mean "required".

Comment: @Buffy I agree, but I'm not sure what your bigger point is.

Comment: You used the word "subverting" which may be too strong. While I agree that your suggested policy is probably a good one, the professor may or may not have the authority to implement it. Work it out with the chair.

Comment: @Buffy Ok - edited. Probably can't get too much more specific without knowing exactly what their uni's registration system allows.

Comment: My main point was not to tell students to sign up/waitlist and *then* pick; that's really unfair and could be a headache for the students involved if they aren't picked.

Comment: I'm a bit bemused that you think instruction discretion is a recipe for disaster. I mean won't post their degree hiring be mostly based upon interviewer discretion? Why do we not trust instructors to make these choices?

Comment: @curious I don't think very many people think interviews are inherently fair or unbiased or even good. And besides, I only said that because you only proposed looking at GPA

Comment: Sure. I appreciate your inputs! No offense intended!

Answer (score 2):

This is something individual instructors should not be deciding.

There are university-wide course requirements that students must meet to get their degrees.  There must be university-wide policies to ensure that students can register for courses that meet those requirements.  That policy should be enforced by the registration software, not instructors.  The details of the policy should vary by institution.